# Typus route order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, typus

It used to be that you could load Typus routes exactly where you needed them by placing

```
  Typus::Routes.draw(map)
```

at the appropriate point in your routes.rb file. It seems that this is no longer supported and that they're always loaded after all of the application routes. This causes problems with catchall routes which must be defined last. Does anyone know how to control the load order for typus now? Is there a way to get them defined before any of the app routes rather than after? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got around it by leaving my catch-all routes at the end of my apps routes.rb BUT excluding it from matching for Typus urls:

```
# A catch all route
match '*path' => 'content#show', :constraints => lambda{|request|
  !request.path.starts_with?("/admin") # excluded if typus will be taking it...
}
```

This may or may now work for you...

Comment: Yeah, this is a reasonable solution. Just wish it could be done as cleanly as it used to be.

Comment: Yep this was a good solution given typus's unfortunate method of handling routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same answer.

At the moment I have resorted to copying the contents from typus's config/routes.rb and placing it into my routes.rb file, before the catchall route.

It's a horrible, hackish solution, but it's solving my immediate problem.

Example:

```
  # TODO: KLUDGE: MANUALLY BRING THE TYPUS ROUTES IN
  #       Typus used to provide :
  #           Typus::Routes.draw(map)
  #       But that is no longer the case.
  scope "admin", :module => :admin, :as => "admin" do

    match "/" => "dashboard#show", :as => "dashboard"
    match "user_guide" => "base#user_guide"

    if Typus.authentication == :session
      resource :session, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy], :controller => :session
      resources :account, :only => [:new, :create, :show, :forgot_password] do
        collection do
          get :forgot_password
          post :send_password
        end
      end
    end

    Typus.models.map { |i| i.to_resource }.each do |resource|
      match "#{resource}(/:action(/:id(.:format)))", :controller => resource
    end

    Typus.resources.map { |i| i.underscore }.each do |resource|
      match "#{resource}(/:action(/:id(.:format)))", :controller => resource
    end
  end
  # END KLUDGE

  # Catch all to the state page handler
  match '/:page' => 'pages#show', :as => 'page'
```